# What is wrong with this if condition of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with ZSH installed. I have this bash script for checking if a directory exist.

Even though i have a directory called "~/.config", the condition is always negative. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code.

**setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "~/.config" ] ; then
  echo "Directory exist"
else
  echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

Made the file executable by using `chmod +x ./setup.sh`
output is always `Does not exist`

Comment: `~` is not expanded to your home directory when it's quoted. Try: `[ -d ~/.config ]`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have written `"~/.config"` it will be treated as literal string. To allow for `~` shell expansions you need to leave it unquoted:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d ~/.config ] ; then
  echo "Directory exist"
else
  echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

This is well explained by [Bash Pitfals, 26. echo "~"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22.2BAH4.22):

> **26. echo "~"**
>
> Tilde expansion only applies when '~' is unquoted. In this example echo writes '~' to stdout, rather than the path of the user's home directory.
>
> Quoting path parameters that are expressed relative to a user's home directory should be done using $HOME rather than '~'. For instance consider the situation where $HOME is "/home/my photos".
>
> ```
> "~/dir with spaces" # expands to "~/dir with spaces"
> ~"/dir with spaces" # expands to "~/dir with spaces"
> ~/"dir with spaces" # expands to "/home/my photos/dir with spaces"
> "$HOME/dir with spaces" # expands to "/home/my photos/dir with spaces"`
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried without the double quotes and it's now working.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, double quotes (`"..."`) suppress glob and related expansions, such as `*`, `~` and others.

Double quotes retain shell variable expansion; single quotes (`'...'`) suppress both glob expansion and shell variable expansion.  Thus, they are each useful in different contexts.

But in contexts where you need `*`, `~`, and so forth to be meaningful, you need unquoted expressions.  ... Just watch out, because unexpected things can happen due to expansion if you are not careful.